# How can I give the illuision of a voice that the speakers himself hears?

Tags: voice

In other words what's the difference between the voice that is picked by a microphone and what the speaker himself hears when he speaks?

Answer (score 1):

The voice you hear when you speak is a mix of the sound that comes out of your mouth and the bones of your crane vibrating. 
This probably has a very different filter from one person to the other.

I guess that most people hear some emphasis on the lower end and lack some airy details.

Usually in movies, they use a short reverb and a boost somewhere between 160 and 450 depending on the voice.

Comment: Interesting. do you know an example from a movie?

Comment: I do not have an example on the top of my head, but I can easily think of all the post-explosion tinnitus scenes and the sound of the people breathing. Also, the reverb is not to make it sound natural, but to tell the viewer that this sound is not diegetic. (think, Homer's head voice)

Answer (score 0):

You may be talking about **binaural recording**.

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binaural_recording)

> Binaural recording is a method of recording sound that uses two
>   microphones, arranged with the intent to create a 3-D stereo sound
>   sensation for the listener of actually being in the room with the
>   performers or instruments.